# determining unknown value c for a sum of independent random variables

Tags: probability-theory

$X_1, X_2$, and $X_3$ are independent random variables with $X_k \sim N(0,k)$. (So, for example, $X_2$ is a normal variable having mean $0$ and variance $2$). Determine the value of $c$ such that
$$c(12X_1^2+6X_2^2+4X_3^2)$$
has a $\chi_3^2$ distribution.

I know that if $Z_1, Z_2,...,Z_n$ are iid random variables $\sim N(0,1)$, then
$$Z_1^2 + Z_2^2 + ... + Z_n^2 \sim \chi_n^2$$

I am having trouble figuring out where to start with this problem (i.e. what does it get set equal to?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $X_i\sim\mathcal{N}(0,i)$, independently for $i=1,2,3$

$\implies \frac{X_i}{\sqrt i}\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, independently for $i=1,2,3$

$\implies \frac{X_i^2}{i}\sim\chi^2_{(1)}$, independently for $i=1,2,3$

$\implies X_1^2+\frac{X_2^2}{2}+\frac{X_3^2}{3}\sim\chi^2_{(3)}$

So equate $c(12X_1^2+6X_2^2+4X_3^2)$ with $ X_1^2+\frac{X_2^2}{2}+\frac{X_3^2}{3}$ to find the value of $c$.

Comment: Another source provided this as an answer: Use the fact that if $Y_1,Y_2,Y_3$ are i.i.d standard normal random variables then $Y_1+Y_2+Y_3\sim \chi_{(3)}^2$. Supposing that $k$ is the variance, we may write $X_i=\sqrt{i}Z_i$ for $i=1,2,3$ and note that $Z_1,Z_2,Z_3$ are independent. Hence
$$
c(12X_1^2+6X_2^2+4X_3^2)=c(12Z_1^2+12Z_2^2+12Z_3^2)
$$
Thus $12c=1$ whence $c=1/12$. I was confused at where the 1 came from and why you can set it equal to 1

Comment: @chelebele403 I assume you have no more doubts regarding this question. But it should be $Y_1^2+Y_2^2+Y_3^2\sim\chi^2_{(3)}$ when $Y_i$'s are iid standard normal in your above statement and not the way you have written.